# How to pass changes to remote from new branch

Tags: git

I have a repository with a master branch and a remote qa branch. I wish to create a local branch called "issue-xxx" and pass the changes I have made on my machine to this qa branch. How would i go about doing this? At present I have done the following:

```
git checkout -b issue-xxx
```

returns files that are changed on my local machine and the notification "switched to a new branch 'issue-xxx'. I then typed:

```
git remote show https://username@bitbucket.org/company/project.git
```

And received:

```
remote https://username@bitbucket.org/company/project.git
Fetch URL: https://username@bitbucket.org/company/project.git
Push  URL: https://username@bitbucket.org/company/project.git
HEAD branch: master
Local refs configured for 'git push':
issue-xxx pushes to issue-xxx (fast-forwardable)
master    pushes to master    (up to date)
qa        pushes to qa        (up to date)
```

I have therefore created the issue branch I think. I need to now pass the changes from issues-xxx branch to the qa branch. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant, how to push a local branch to the remote with different name.

If you want to do this, then use this command:

`git push remote local-branch-name:remote-branch-name`

In your case it is:

`git push remote issue-xxx:qa`

But I recommend you to use an effective and proven workflow. You can read more here:

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions. One is to locally checkout the `qa` branch and merge the changes from your `issue-xxx` branch: `git checkout qa && git merge issue-xxx && git push`. Of course, instead of merging you could also rebase.

You can also push directly to `qa` on `origin`: `git checkout issue-xxx && git push origin issue-xxx:qa`.